# Python, не могу вытащить из json-а данные

Tags: python, json, api

получаю ответ на запрос в формате json, но не могу вытащить из него нужные значения по ключу.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint 

r = requests.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=kiev&key=..............')

data = r.json()
pprint(data)
city_name = data['data']['city_name'] 
print (city_name)
```

На строке city_name выдаёт:"list indices must be integers or slices, not str".
Читал документацию, смотрел видео, не могу понять, что я делаю не так.
Вот прикрепляю скрин, на котором такой же код работает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на скрине вижу `data['city_name']` а у вас `data['data']['city_name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так на скрине обращение идет к другому `api`.
в вашем случае чтобы получить город надо сделать так

```
print (data['data'][0]['city_name'])
```

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо, теперь работает!